# TypeError trying to compare texts using for loop

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, similarity

I am trying to compare texts scraped from different websites to each other. 
I have a list of text got from a column in a dataframe. To compare texts in this list, I have tried to use similarity (I do not know if there is another way to do the same). 
This is the code:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

titles = filtered_dataset['Titles'].tolist()

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

def get_jaccard_sim(str1, str2): 
    a = set(str1.split()) 
    b = set(str2.split())
    c = a.intersection(b)
    return float(len(c)) / (len(a) + len(b) - len(c))

similarities=[]
j_similarities=[]
for title in titles:
    similarity=similar(title, title+1)
    jacc_similarity=get_jaccard_sim(title,  title+1) # I would like to compare the first text to the others; then the second one, and so on...
```

I have got the following error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

because of

```
similarity=similar(title, title+1)
jacc_similarity=get_jaccard_sim(title,  title+1)
```

Could you please help me to fix the error to compare the texts?

Comment: Sorry, but unfortunately I think there might be a problem in the comparison. What I would like to compare is a string "title" in "Titles" list to each items within that list. I think that title +str(1) cannot do the same, but maybe I am saying something wrong. Could you please confirm that this is ok? Undoubtedly using str(1) fix the error, but does not allow me to compare the texts. I do not know if this is another question. Please let me know if I need to open a new one. Thanks @Nuwan Madushanka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You adding **title** (*String*) and **1** (*int*) but in python you cannot add *string* and *integer* if you wanna add a string to an integer change that integer to a string. ex: "sampleString"+str(1) = "sampleString1" , *str() function changes 1 to '1'*. so here type("sampleString") is string and type(str(1)) is string. so you can add both strings together.

use this code

```
similarity=similar(title, title+str(1))
jacc_similarity=get_jaccard_sim(title,  title+str(1))
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

well, You're concatenating string and integer that's why it's through an error. Here the title is String and 1 is an integer you can use below the code for avoiding the error

```
similarity=similar(title, title+str(1))
jacc_similarity=get_jaccard_sim(title,  title+str(1))
```